# How to parse a date array in php

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have a date that I'm getting from a date picker. It is returning an `array()` like the following...

```
array(12) { 
    ["year"]=> int(2016) 
    ["month"]=> int(11) 
    ["day"]=> int(24) 
    ["hour"]=> bool(false) 
    ["minute"]=> bool(false) 
    ["second"]=> bool(false) 
    ["fraction"]=> bool(false) 
    ["warning_count"]=> int(0) 
    ["warnings"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["error_count"]=> int(0) 
    ["errors"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["is_localtime"]=> bool(false) 
}
```

I tried to get just the month or the year out of this `array()` utilizing a `foreach()` but no success with it. 
How can I iterate through this `array()` and extract the year or month independently?

Comment: It's an ordinary associative array, you just use `$variable['year']` or `$variable['month']`

Comment: Why do you think you need to iterate? There aren't multiple dates here.

Comment: I thought that I have to iterate through the array to get the keys and store the values in variables.

Comment: Don't you know the key names ?

Comment: @Gilbert It seems like you have a basic misunderstanding about how associative arrays are used.

Comment: Assign it to some variable, like $var = your array, then $var["year"] should return 2016.

Comment: why create new variables at all? just use `$variable['year']`

Comment: This array is from a datepicker but I will be iterating through multiple dates that I `SELECT` from a database and performed some date computations with the date from the datepicker.

Comment: i think you need to rewrite the question, as it stands its not matching up with your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the array elements through [PHP mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) and will return a UNIX Timestamp.

Doesn't look like a multidimensional array, so you shouldn't have to iterate, just access the key like:

```
$year = $array['year'];
// etc
```